# How can I merge two Mbtiles?

Tags: merge, geospatial, qgis, mbtiles

I have created 2 Mbtiles via QGIS: 1) one Mbtile is from zoom 0 until 10 & is a map of the whole world, 2) and another one from zoom 0 until 17 & is a detailed map of one country.

I would like to merge the two Mbtiles, and have the Mbtile of the detailed country overlapping the Mbtile of whole world. Also the merged result to be from zoom 0 til 17 (the whole world would disappear at zoom 10, but the country will remain until zoom 17).

What program/method should I use? Is it possible to merge them via QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tile-join](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#tile-join), it has a bunch of flags so you can customize the output.

Answer (score 0):

I use Python to merge MBTiles files. Be sure to update the matadata table noting the min max zoom. They are just sqlite databases with a unique extension.

This example does not include data validation. I did not test this example -- as it is stripped down from where I batch process output from QGIS.

It is less problematic to use an IDE other than QGIS's python interface. Does not require anything specific to QGIS or PyQGIS.

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite

def processOneSource(srcDB, dstDB):
    # create_index_sql = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tile_index on tiles (zoom_level, tile_column, tile_row);"
    # dstDB.connection.execute(create_index_sql)
    # the index forces an error if there is already a tile for the same zxy

    sqlite_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO tiles (zoom_level, tile_column, tile_row, tile_data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""

    tiles = srcDB.connection.execute('select zoom_level, tile_column, tile_row, tile_data from tiles;')

    for t in tiles:
        z = t[0]
        x = t[1]
        y = t[2]
        data = t[3]

        # example of how you might include exclude tiles
        if not (z == 12 or z == 13 or z == 14 or z == 15 or z == 16):
            continue

        print(str((t[0], t[1], t[2])))

        data_tuple = (t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3])
        try:
            dstDB.connection.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    dstDB.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    srcDB = sqlite.connect("path_to_yourfilename")
    dstDB = sqlite.connect("path_to_yourfilename")
    processOneSource(srcDB, dstDB)
```